# Double hyphen in Taiwanese language carries grammatical function

Tags: macros, xetex, unicode, ligatures

In the Taiwanese language, double hyphen carries grammatical function and is used frequently. Example:

Āu--ji̍t chiah koh lâi. (Come again the day after tomorrow.)

Āu-ji̍t chiah koh lâi. (Come again in the future.)

The problem is that, double hyphen is converted into n-dash. I know that -{}- can stop the conversion. However, the line break is going to happen in between the two hyphens and that has to be prevented, too. Therefore, it becomes

`Āu\mbox{-{}-}{\allowbreak}ji̍t chiah koh lâi.`

This looks convoluted. Since I am using xelatex, I think I might define a command for the sequence, and in the mean time make it looks more like a double hyphen even in the source code.

`\newcommand{\‐‐}{\mbox{‐‐}{\allowbreak}}`

Those ‐ in \‐‐ are not U+002D, but U+2010. Same as those in \mbox, so that I avoid the ligature. And supposedly I can write

`Āu\‐‐ji̍t chiah koh lâi.`

This is much easier to know it is a double hyphen.

However, I got an error message.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

What is puzzling is that

`\newcommand{\‐}{\mbox{‐‐}{\allowbreak}}`

works fine. But it is less than ideal since it does not look like a double hyphen.

If there is no good solution to this, I need to forget about the `\allowbreak`, and just write two U+2010 back to back. But words with double hyphen are long and the typesetting gets ugly.

Comment: Welcome! You can't define `\--` (actually you *somewhat* can, but you'd discard the definition of `\-` and nobody wants it. You might do `\def\0--{\mbox{-}-}` and this would throw errors when `\0` is not followed by two hyphens.

Comment: tex commands can only have a single non-letter so you can have `\-` but not `\$$` and `\-` but not `\--`  You could simply disable the "tex" ligatures so `--` does not make a dash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're able to type in U+2010, then the combination `‐‐` (U+2010 U+2010) won't produce a ligature.

You can *somewhat* define `\--` (with hyphens, but this would erase the definition of `\-`).

A possible alternative would be to use `\0--` (with two hyphens):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\def\0--{‐‐\allowbreak}% two U+2010 in the body

\begin{document}

Āu--ji̍t chiah koh lâi. (Come again the day after tomorrow.) % two hyphens

Āu‐‐ji̍t chiah koh lâi. (Come again the day after tomorrow.) % two U+2010

Āu\0--ji̍t chiah koh lâi. (Come again the day after tomorrow.) % the command

Āu-ji̍t chiah koh lâi. (Come again in the future.)

\parbox[t]{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}Āu\0--ji̍t chiah koh lâi.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good observation. Unicode has a number of code points that solve some LaTeX problems. This was not intentional. It just worked out that way. Many (not all) fonts have characters at the necessary code points. Another good reason to use utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the classic TeX ligatures such as `--` which are not needed in xelatex, you can simply enter an en dash to get a dash.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeXOff]{Arial}

\begin{document}

Āu--ji̍t chiah koh lâi dash–dash.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem that line breaks might be inserted in between the two hyphens.

Comment: @Bêng-HànLûi true I was just looking at that, I might add something later, need to be offline for a bit....